# Cosmos DB parameterised SQL query not working with double quoted parameter

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have this query working fine in the Data Explorer - querying for the existence of a Dictionary item:

`SELECT VALUE COUNT(c) FROM c WHERE not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers["2"])`

Given a container with data set such as (simplified):

```
[
   {
       "Name": "Donald",
       "Answers": {
           "1": {
               "a": 3,
               "isCorrect": false
           },
           "2": {
               "a": 7,
               "isCorrect": false
           }
       },
   },
   {
       "Name": "Boris",
       "Answers": {
           "1": {
               "a": 2,
               "isCorrect": false
           }
       },
   },
]
```

But I'm now trying to parameterise this in code and it doesn't appear to work unless I hardcode the parameter (i.e. Don't parameterise).

**This does not work**:

```
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT VALUE COUNT(c) FROM c WHERE not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers[\"@quNo\"])")
    .WithParameter("@quNo", 2);
```

**But this does work**:

```
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT VALUE COUNT(c) FROM c WHERE not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers[\"2\"])");
```

Any ideas why the parameterisation isn't working?  I presume it is because of the double quotes, but not sure how to work around it.

I've tried changing to a string literal too, e.g.

```
@"SELECT ... <snip> not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers[""@quNo""])";
```

but this also does not work.

**UPDATE:**

I have added a [RequestHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.fluent.cosmosclientbuilder.addcustomhandlers?view=azure-dotnet) to track exactly what is being sent to Cosmos.  When sending parameterised, the format is:

```
{
    "query": "SELECT VALUE [{\"item\": COUNT(c)}]\nFROM c\nWHERE not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers[\"@quNo\"])",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "@quNo",
            "value": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

As per suggestions, I have tried the parameter value as integer or string, but neither work.

Setting the value directly in the query is the only thing that seems to work:

```
{
    "query": "SELECT VALUE [{\"item\": COUNT(c)}]\nFROM c\nWHERE not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers[\"2\"])",
    "parameters": [
    ]
}
```

I assume this must have something to do with escape characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I believe this should work:

```
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT VALUE COUNT(c) FROM c WHERE not IS_DEFINED(c.Answers[@quNo])")
    .WithParameter("@quNo", "2");
```

Comment: Interesting. So what does the request handler send in this case? (Make sure you have `@quNo` without quotes in the query.)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, you are right - I had missed that you were setting the parameter to `"2"` (string value not integer).  I've added `.ToString()` to my integer value and now it works!